# setting up swap space on a triple boot system?

Tags: dual-boot, backup, swap

First off,

OS:
Ubuntu 13.10,
Kali-Linux,
Windows 7 Ultimate

H/W:
asus laptop, 
i7,
1tb hdd,
8gb ram

Since my hard drive already had 3 primary partitions I cannot create a dedicated swap partition for Ubuntu and Kali-Linux. I want to have 20gb of swap space for Ubuntu and 20gb for Kali-Linux.

My question is:

**Is it possible and how should I go about it?**

A link to a how to would be great! I'm trying to avoid system errors, and blue screens, and other bothersome issues.

Secondly, I use symantec ghost to build two hard drvies at a time (an exact copy in case of a system crash). Will it be able to see and copy `ext4` partitions(Kali-linux and Ubuntu13.10) onto a second hard drive? Will they be interchangeable?

It works for my windows 7 install but I wasn't sure about `ext4` and also my `grub`.

Comment: I don't see why it's not possible. As long as you specify the correct partition to use as swap in both OSes, and you format that partition as a swap space, it should work.

Comment: You can have both swaps in one extended partition as logicals. But you only need two swaps if you hibernate and with dual booting you probably should not hibernate. And with 8GB of RAM you only need a little more than 8GB for swap to hold all of RAM when hibernating. Actual math is 8GiB required. But if not hibernating you probably only need 2 or 3GB for swap and that may never be used. You may also want another NTFS shared data partition for any data you might want to share between all your installs. Better to only mount Windows system as read only and use a shared NTFS as read/write.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is solution for you to have swap on file. You not need partition and can create one for ubuntu one for kali on / partition.

create file with name swapfile

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=21474836480
```

count is size of file

create swap "file system"

```
mkswap /swapfile
```

turn on swap

```
swapon /swapfile
```

write to /etc/fstab

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab    
/swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

But this solution have only one downside, you waist 40 gb of disk for swap.